# Bind WAN IP to LAN (under router) IIS

Tags: networking, iis, firewall, local-area-network, wide-area-network

I am hosting my own website on my local machine and set up a virtual server on my router and everything works like a charm.

In IIS, i cannot bind the WAN IP, as it doesn't show up, and if I type it manually, the website does not work.  I know that there is something else I need to do, such as bind the WAN IP to my local machine as the title says, but how would one do that?

I am sure all the hosting companies are doing something similar to this, but I cannot find anything on how to do it.

Comment: Is your IIS machine behind a firewall?  What is your IIS server's normal address and give us the first two octets of your WAN address (e.g. 12.52.x.x)

Comment: iis is behind router and windows firewall. but as i said, the website is working from the web. my problem is that i need to identify (by code) that the external ip is local ip, so i need to bind it to iis.
my internal address is 192.168.1.2 (192.168.1.1 would be the router) the wan ip is 78.131.xxx.xxx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you are behind a physical [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) (and I know you are because of your [RFC 1918 address](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918#section-3)), you cannot bind your WAN IP to your ethernet NIC on the IIS server.  Your IIS server must not be NAT'd to make this happen.  Most people put it in a publicly-addressed DMZ.

That said, it's still unclear to me how adding 78.131.x.x to your local IIS server really helps.  I presume you're looking at something like `X-Forwarded-For` in the HTTP header, but why you *must* bind your IP locally to IIS is still unclear.  Also, it's unclear how this helps, since you presumably could just hardcode the WAN address in to your webapp.

Comment: Physical NAT is my router ? (192.168.xxx.xxx) ?
or did you ment the 78.131.xxx.xxx address? which is a static ip?
i do not want to hard code the address because this is a development machine, and i do not know where the client will host the site.

Comment: Your NAT functionality usually happens on the router/firewall that terminates the connection from your ISP.  You can probably can find the external address your client uses dynamically with a quick query to a service like [What's my IP](http://www.whatismyip.com/) during your web service startup

Comment: if i will disconnect the router and connect my computer directly would that solve it?

Comment: Well, that's one way to fix your development problem, but if your client is security-savvy, they will put the webapp behind a firewall / http load-balancer, so you still need to find a way to solve this problem.  Furthermore, leaving an IIS development machine unfirewalled in the wild internet is more brave than I would be

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out how your router/firewall does **port-forwarding** then forward all requests to port 80 of your public ip to the dev server private ip.

Comment: Actually, he had already done that before he asked the question

Comment: @Mike, there is nothing in the question that hints that the OP has done this at all.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers, there is plenty, but I guess it's not obvious to you.  The OP already commented that his address was 192.168.1.2.  It's impossible to serve web pages to the internet using this address without port-forwarding or NAT

Comment: At the very least, It's now clear what key words he needs to search his router documentation for, or request his ISP to implement for him.

Comment: @Both of you guyz - The OP (Hey thats me) also said the external IP is 78.131.xxx.xxx, and also said everything is working. also i said that i have setup Virtual Server (Which is exactly the same as Port-Forwarding) the problem was (and solved) that IIS could not bind the WAN ip, this was solved by removing the router, and connecting directly from the PC (this way the WAN IP is part of IIS)

Comment: Which would mean he has approximately a very short time before that box is owned. Bad things happen when you put windows directly on the internet. Also port forwarding creates a 1:1 relationship between a public IP and a private IP; virtual server creates a 1:many relationship, and being that he only spoke of one machine, port forwarding is the most appropriate in this case.

Comment: @Timothy, No you don't even understand his problem. He needs to map his external IP address to a web application hosted on IIS; for whatever reason his web app uses that address to make decisions. That's why he wanted to put IIS directly on the internet. He chose the lazy way out in spite of advice to the contrary